# mutations in javascript - best practices

Tags: javascript, mutation

I have a colleague that argues that we need to avoid mutations in this case:

```
const doSomethingWithData = async () => {
  const dataObject = await getData();
  dataObject.message = "hi";
}
```

He would prefer that it be:

```
const doSomethingWithData = async () => {
  const dataObject = await getData();
  const copyOfDataObject = Object.assign({}, dataObject); 
  copyOfDataObject.message = "hi";
}
```

What is everyone's thought on this?  We call around a lot of functions in our code and a lot of the functions return an object... It's extremely tedious to copy every object that is returned by a function (also - seems like memory would be bad too?)...

edit: apologies - this seems like an opinion-question

I'd like to rephrase my question to how would you make it such that dataObject is immutable?  Assume dataObject has nested properties...

Comment: It's always a good idea not to modify `const` variable, even if it is an array or an object. In my opinion, you can also use object destructuring {...dataObject}

Comment: JavaScript is not a functional programming language, and objects are meant to be mutated.

Comment: Objects hold state, you modify them as the state changes.

Comment: There is no need to make every variable const, you can use let instead. Choosing between them should be aligned to what your program achieves to do and the architecture youre using.

Comment: @Barmar I disagree with you. When you create an object as `const`, you mean that this should stay constant and it shouldn't mutate anymore. It is bad to tweak that const object only because it is possible

Comment: @DominikMatis That's not what `const` means in JavaScript, it just means you're not reassigning the variable, it says nothing about what the variable refers to. It's common to update arrays that are in const variables.

Comment: Also `Object.assign({}, dataObject)` would only create a shallow copy and doesn't prevent from nested/complex properties mutation

Comment: @DominikMatis Anyway, the question isn't about `const`, it's about modifying objects in general.

Comment: Yeah that's correct, it's like constant pointer in C for ex.

Comment: @Barmar well, in that case, modifying object is totally fine... I only saw const soo

Comment: The second code snippet makes no sense. It is still modifying the original object, the copy is just not used. And if it were to set the property on the copy, then why would you assign a property on an object that would get discarded right after? Just don't call this function it does nothing.

Comment: @Kaiido - thanks for pointing it out - I just edited my post so hopefully it makes more sense.

Comment: The second part of my (edited) comment still holds: "why would you assign a property on an object that would get discarded right after? Just don't call this function it does nothing"

Comment: @Kaiido - can you explain - where is `copyOfDataObject` getting discarded?

Comment: Nothing holds a reference to it outside of the function's scope-> it's discarded as soon as the function ran.

Comment: Barmer has given the correct use case for const above. Its more of a software engineering related thing than programming, since mutation technically possible. Its better to deep copy const in appropriate places, but there is a performance overhead for those deep copies also. It boils down to the team or architectural patters you're using.

Comment: Axios might use some form of caching. When it does that and it does not return a clean object AND does not disallow mutation, you could affect the state of other parts in the code that use Axios. This can possibly create very hard to find bugs.

Answer (score 3):

It's a good practice to avoid any object mutation in JS unless you cannot avoid it. As you told it's tedious to copy evry object and create a new one out of it, for that reason developers use libraries such as ImmutableJS or any other libraries either third party or own Utility which takes care of not mutatating the object.

Comment: I've never heard this advice before.

Comment: mutability leads to unpredictable behavior and Immutability leads to much simpler application application developement.

Comment: How does making a copy every time you want to update an object, as in the code snippet, make things simpler?

Comment: Thats the reason I suggested immutable-js reather than makinga copy each time.

Comment: Asutosh - are you saying for all your code when an object is passed around - you use ImmutableJS?  You see - I have many tables in my database and many functions that retrieve specific data from the tables... each time the data is passed around in my code... am I to make it immutable with ImmutableJS?

Comment: @deblearns1 It depends, if you are building new application from scratch please use the librarray, else it's a big task to rewrite your existing code.

Comment: I just glanced at the documentation. Even immutable-js provides transient mutable objects for use internally within functions that build up objects incrementally.

Comment: Exacyly thats the case of not creating a copy of object unnncessiraly as suggested in my  answer "unless you cannot avoid it"

Answer (score -1):

I prefer use mutation when working with array and stacks. In other working cases i always avoid of using mutations, because it can be a way to lost control what's going on in the code. :))

Comment: Hi Paul - curious - how would you approach the situation I have in my post?

Comment: it depends on all context of your task. if it's a small modification - hmm, why not? but if you working with big object and update it in different functions/many times/et.c - i prefer to avoid mutation